# How does nginx worker process share the 'listen socket'

Tags: nginx

This http://aosabook.org/en/nginx.html says that "worker processes accept new requests from a shared ""listen" socket and execute a highly efficient run-loop inside each

I looked at hte code but did not understand how the socket is shared. Is it the case that the master process creates a listen queue, binds and then forks. In that case, how does the OS decide which worker process to hand over the incoming connection to? Is it round robin or random? I am assuming that different OS may have different policies

Comment: Yes, it's bound before the fork, but as far as I remember children have to synchronise their `accept` calls themselves.

Comment: Thanks. What does synchronizing accept exactly mean? In the scenario where you have multiple children blocked on an accept socket which is actually a copy from the parent process, which child will come out of accept? That should be OS dependent, but I don't see any info on this

Comment: I don't remember this much, probably something wrong would happen, because when I did it (quite a while ago — ~15 years), I used semaphore lock to avoid parallel `accept()` calls. Again, I don't remember the details, but most likely I've done some research first.

Answer (score -2):

> In that case, how does the OS decide which worker process to hand over the incoming connection to?

The question sounds exactly like "how does the OS decide which process will get to run".

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scheduling_%28computing%29#Operating_system_process_scheduler_implementations

Comment: Only if you ignore the details, but that's kind of the point.