# On Windows platform, how does nginx master process share listen sockets to worker?

Tags: windows, sockets, nginx

I have look through the code of Nginx on Windows version.
But I don't understand how master is sharing listening sockets with workers.

It is straight forward on Linux. When it fork(), workers inherit the file descriptions from the master.

But when it comes to the Windows version, in the CreateProcess() function, it specify the "bInheritHandles" argument field as "0", meaning it does not inherit the handles!

So then how the workers share listening sockets with master?

I did read the code for two days just to find the answer to this question.
But I still can not understand it.

Thanks!

*This question looks very similar with the another one [How does nginx worker process share the 'listen socket'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19598444/how-does-nginx-worker-process-share-the-listen-socket/39907554#39907554)
But it is not. Because that one is asking about the one on Linux platform.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesn't.  Instead, on Windows each nginx worker process creates its own listening sockets, and uses them to accept connections.

Creating listening sockets on the same ports is possible as nginx uses `setsockopt(SO_REUSEADDR)` on listening sockets, and this allows completely duplicate listening sockets on Windows.

Only one of these duplicate listening sockets actually work though, and here comes the first limitation of nginx for Windows as listed in [the documentation](http://nginx.org/en/docs/windows.html#known_issues):

> Although several workers can be started, only one of them actually does any work.

Note well that nginx for Windows "is considered to be a *beta* version".

Comment: Thank you so much for the clear explanation! It helps a lot!

Comment: Would nginx running in WSL have multiple workers actually doing work?

Comment: @Marc, WSL is expected to provide Linux-compatible environment, so nginx is expected to work fine with multiple workers as long as WSL is implemented properly. Note though that there were reports that there are [issues at least with WSL 1](http://mailman.nginx.org/pipermail/nginx/2020-May/059423.html), likely due to incorrect emulation of some socket-related syscalls. A better solution might be to run nginx on an actual Unix/Linux system instead.